# Python replaces pattern with ΓÇª

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to replace patterns such as `/xe3` and `/x99` by white space or nothing.

```
import re

t = re.sub(r'\\x[a-z][0-9]|\\x[0-9][0-9]', ' ','guy\xe2\x80\xa6\xe2\x80\xa6realdonaldtrump')

print(t)
```

But I'm getting following result:

```
guyΓÇªΓÇªrealdonaldtrump
```

How do I get rid of `ΓÇª`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current script did not even run for me, but if you just want to strip off all hexadecimal characters, then try removing any hexadecimal character which is not ASCII:

```
t = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]+', ' ', 'guy\xe2\x80\xa6\xe2\x80\xa6realdonaldtrump')
print(t)

guy realdonaldtrump
```

Comment: for me the string handling of python makes it so that this string does not contain any `x` ... it contains the translated characters. You can not find any `x[0-9a-fA-F]+` in it. If you could you would have problem with `t = re.sub(r'x[0-9a-fA-F]+', ' ', 'guy\xe2\x80\xa6\xe2\x80\xa6AbeLincoln')` - it would remove `Abe` as well...

Comment: I'm still getting 'ΓÇª' instead of space. Not sure what the deal is.

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to Tim's answer:

## FYI: "ΓÇª" is a bad decoding of "…"

"Ellipsis" is a special character. It is three dots but not saved as three characters ("...") but instead as a single character: "…"

You have this hexstring "\xe2\x80\xa6\xe2\x80\xa6".
This is "\xe2\x80\xa6" (or 0xE280A6 or E280A6 or E2 80 A6) twice.

If you decode hexstring 0xE280A6 as UTF-8, then it turns into this: …
If you decode hexstring 0xE280A6 as "Code page 437", then it turns into this: ΓÇª

Decoding as UTF-8 will give you the correct result:

```
$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code UTF-8
…

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code UTF-8 -x hex
\u2026

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code UTF-8 -x name
\N{HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS}

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code UTF-8 --to-code UTF-8 | xxd
00000000: e280 a6                                  ...
```

Decoding as CP437 will give you the wrong result:

```
$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code CP437 --to-code UTF-8
ΓÇª

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code CP437 --to-code UTF-8 -x hex
\u0393\u00C7\u00AA

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code CP437 --to-code UTF-8 -x name
\N{GREEK CAPITAL LETTER GAMMA}\N{LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA}\N{FEMININE ORDINAL INDICATOR}

$ echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code CP437 --to-code UTF-8 | xxd
00000000: ce93 c387 c2aa                           ......
```

#### Details:

- https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm Unicode Character 'HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS' (U+2026)
- https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/IBM437/list.htm
  Complete Character List for IBM437
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis
- https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jump?q=uconv

### BTW: Same decoding for CP437, CP860 and CP865

Now "uconv" can do 102 codepages and three of them have the same mappings from hexstring 0xE280A6 to unicode: CP437, CP860 and CP865

```
$ for CODEPAGE in $(uconv --list | grep -iE '\<cp[^0][0-9]+\>' -o | tr [a-z] [A-Z] | sort --version-sort); do echo -n -e '\xE2\x80\xA6' | uconv --from-code "${CODEPAGE}" --to-code UTF-8 > "${CODEPAGE}" 2>&1; done
✗

$ ls -1 -- CP* | wc --lines
102
✓

$ xxd CP437
00000000: ce93 c387 c2aa                           ......
✓

$ cat CP437
ΓÇª
✓

$ sha256sum CP* | grep $(sha256sum CP437 | cut -d" " -f1)
4ec179258edb8b1e30f87e6ffa5a281974ed06fafce306c5e0067b312c13fae1 *CP437
4ec179258edb8b1e30f87e6ffa5a281974ed06fafce306c5e0067b312c13fae1 *CP860
4ec179258edb8b1e30f87e6ffa5a281974ed06fafce306c5e0067b312c13fae1 *CP865
✓
```

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_856